# Is it safe to concatenate `null` with a string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, null, concatenation

I didn't found a statement about the compatibility between strings and `null` in the docs, but trying this on PHP 5.5:

```
echo 'foo' . null . 'bar';
```

prints out `foobar`.

I wonder if this behaviour is guaranteed, or "safe" to do (in SQL, for example, it is not)? Or asking the other way: Would I ever need to check for `null` before concatenating strings? Like

```
echo 'foo' . (($mystring === null) ? '' : $mystring) . 'bar';
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting):

> **NULL** is always converted to an empty string.

---

Yes, you can rely on that behavior.